# Birchas Kohanim if a non-Jew is present

Tags: halacha, gentiles, birchas-kohanim

Is there an issue with Kohanim saying Birchas Kohanim when a non-Jew is present?

Comment: Why do you think there would be? ([edit])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [שו"ת יוסף אומץ להחיד"א סי' ע' ס"ד](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1064&st=&pgnum=183) he discusses this concept.

It seems that some had this custom - to not say Birchas Kohanim when a non-Jew was present.

It seems to be based on a misconception, and **he rules that there is no issue with it.**

Background:

In [Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim (25:20)](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_4.html#HtmpReportNum0009_L2) the Halacha states:

> **כ** יִהְיוּ עֲשָׂרָה בְּמָקוֹם אֶחָד וְאוֹמְרִים קַדִּישׁ וּקְדֻשָּׁה, אֲפִלּוּ מִי שֶׁאֵינוֹ עִמָּהֶם  יָכוֹל לַעֲנוֹת, וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁצָּרִיךְ שֶׁלֹּא יְהֵא מַפְסִיק טִנּוּף אוֹ  עַכּוּ''ם.

A minyan is defined when the 10 are in the same room. Even people in other locations can answer Kadish and Kedusha. Some say that this only applies if nothing disgusting - nor  עַכּוּ''ם - is between the Minyan and those in the other location.

Seems like some people took this to mean that if there's a non-Jew between them and the Cohanim, it would *invalidate* their ability to answer Amen, so they didn't do Birkat Cohanim if he was in the room.

However, the Halacha stated refers to another location - not the same room.

Besides, the Be'er Heitav ([ibid](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_4.html#HtmpReportNum0009_L2)) states that  עַכּוּ''ם refers to an Avoda Zara, not a non-Jew.

> **עכו''ם.** ר''ל שלא יהא עבודת אלילים מפסקת אבל עובד עבודת אלילים אינו מפסיק. מגן אברהם וכך כתב דבר שמואל סי' קפ''ט: 
>   ‏

Sources / Hat tip:

- [המדור ההלכתי - על ברכת כהנים כשיש נכרי](http://hagabay.net/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A-%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%91%D7%90%D7%99/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%99/253-2011-03-09-13-52-41.html)
- [נשיאת כפים כשיש גוי בבית הכנסת](http://www.haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=922&cat=10&haoro=5)